# String comparison

Tags: conditionals, strings, xstring, xifthen

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen, xstring}

\newcommand{\IfOne}[3]{
   \if\TokenIsIn#1
     #2
   \else
     #3
   \fi
}

\newcommand{\IfTwo}[3]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{\TokenIsIn}{#1}}{#2}{#3}
}

\newcommand{\IfThree}[3]{
\IfBeginWith{\TokenIsIn}{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\newcommand{\TokenIsIn}{}
\newcommand{\settok}[1]{\global\let\TokenIsIn=#1}

\settok{a}

\begin{document}
\IfOne{a}{Yes}{No}\\
\IfTwo{a}{Yes}{No}\\
\IfThree{a}{Yes}{No}
\end{document}
```

Output

```
Yes
No
No
```

Why do the `\IfTwo` and `\IfThree` return `No`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\let\TokenIsIn=a`, the control sequence `\TokenIsIn` becomes an unexpandable token; more precisely, it becomes an “implicit `a`”.

The tests `\if\TokenIsIn a` and `\ifx\TokenIsIn a` return true, but `\ifthenelse` makes the comparison in a different way; basically, `\ifthenelse{\equal{X}{Y}}` does something like

```
\edef\first{X}\edef\second{Y}\ifx\first\second
```

and this test returns false when `X` is `\TokenIsIn` and `Y` is `a`, because `\first` and `\second` don't have the same first level expansion: an implicit token is not the same as the token.

For `\IfBeginWith` the situation is a bit more complicated, but essentially the test fails because something like `\edef\first{\TokenIsIn}` is performed as well and, in `\edef`, `\TokenIsIn` is *not* changed into `a`.

With `\ifthen` and `\IfBeginWith` only *explicit* token should be used.

The three tests return true if you do

```
\newcommand{\settok}[1]{\gdef\TokenIsIn{#1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\IfBeginWith` uses this code (shown by `\meaning\IfBeginWith`)

```
\long macro:->\@ifstar {\let \@xs@assign \@xs@expand@and@detokenize
\@xs@IfBeginWith@@ }{\let \@xs@assign \@xs@expand@and@assign \@xs@IfBeginWith@@
```

i.e. it does expansion and detokenization of the input code `\TokenIsIn`, but `\if`... does expansion until it finds non-expandable tokens, which is the case (at least I think so) with `\global\let\...=#1`, which isn't expandable and it can't evaluate to be `true` (or 'No' here).

However, using a `\newtoks` register and expanding (or better: making it expandable) it within `\TokenIsIn` with `\the\MyToken` does not keep `\if...` from expanding the construct.

See the example output for the letter b, which should yield `No` for all macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen, xstring}

\newcommand{\IfOne}[3]{%
   \if\TokenIsIn#1
   #2%
   \else
   #3%
   \fi
}

\newcommand{\IfTwo}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\TokenIsIn}{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\IfThree}[3]{%
  \IfBeginWith{\TokenIsIn}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\TokenIsIn}{\the\MyToken}

\newtoks\MyToken

\newcommand{\settok}[1]{\MyToken={#1}}%

\settok{a}


\begin{document}



\IfOne{a}{Yes}{No}

\IfTwo{a}{Yes}{No}

\IfThree{a}{Yes}{No}

\IfOne{b}{Yes}{No}

\IfTwo{b}{Yes}{No}

\IfThree{b}{Yes}{No}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I might sound naive as I am just a beginner to tex. Does this mean that `\let` is not a reliable way to assign variables? Or is it that the commands in `xifthen` and `xstring` packages are not robust?

Comment: @Miheer: `\let\...` is good for assigning macros to each other, making a copy of the macro thereby (there are other applications too), but I doubt its usefulness for tokens. (tokens are no macros)

Answer (score 2):

From another angle, the `stringstrings` package is very slow and is primarily intended for regular expressions.  But if your problem is of that style, then it has some useful routines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}

\begin{document}
\def\mystring{dcbadcbadcba}

\findchars{\mystring}{a} a's found in string

Position \whereischar{\mystring}{a} is where the first `a' is found

\testmatchingchar{\mystring}{3}{a}
Character 3 \ifmatchingchar is \else is not \fi an `a'. 

\testmatchingchar{\mystring}{4}{a}
Character 4 \ifmatchingchar is \else is not \fi an `a'. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I see some stray spaces are being produced by the `\whereischar` macro